# Question tag edit doesn't show up properly in edit history

Tags: bug, design, revision-history

When looking at the edit history of the post I noticed that tag only edits show up weird. Notice the extra highlighting between the tags:

[image: Tag edit]

<sup>Found on this [questions history (revision 2).](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42110730/revisions)</sup>

However it shows up correctly in the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15472053).

Produced on Windows 10, Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 and IE 11.576.14393.0.

Comment: Reproducible on Windows 7 with Chrome 56.0.2924.87, Firefox 51.0.1, and IE 11.0.9600.18537.

Comment: Just another example to show it is not just that post: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15472376

Comment: @NathanOliver Confused me for a second then because you'd linked to the review not the revision history.

Comment: @Braiam As you've edited the tags on this question the problem now occurs on this post!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Sorry about that,  I wanted to find a review that edited the tags to confirm the review screen renders properly.

Comment: I was aiming for the punch line...